# Functions not actualizing

Tags: vba, excel

I execute a VBA code that takes a database, treats it and export it into a sheet. This is working fine. However, I have a sheet that produces graphs depending on the data in the particular sheet. The datas does not actualize. I have to enter the cell and click enter to actualize it. I'm pretty sure there is an easier way to do this. Calculation is set to automatic but that doesn't seem to change anything.

In my cell, I have my own vba function that needs to be updated once the report is done. When I click the cell and then enter, the result is updated but I would like this to be done automatically. I hope this is clearer !

Thanks in advance,

Etienne NOEL

HEre is the code of my function

```
   Public Function number_of_appearances(term As String, sheet As String, column As Integer) As Integer


Application.Volatile
    Dim number_of_rows As Integer
    Dim appearances As Integer
    Dim row As Integer

    appearances = 0
    row = 1
    number_of_rows = Worksheets(sheet).UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Do While row <= number_of_rows
        If Worksheets(sheet).Cells(row, column).Value = term Then
            appearances = appearances + 1
        End If
         row = row + 1
    Loop


    number_of_appearances = appearances

End Function
```

> A cell example of a user of the function

```
=number_of_appearances('test';'sheet1'; 3)
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly what "actualize" means in this question.  Do you have formulas which are not calculating?  In that case have you tried calling Application.CalculateFull ?

Comment: Yep, I tried that. I updated the post with more details.

Comment: Are you by any chance using the `Worksheet_Change` event to call the VBA function that "needs to be updated once the report is done"? This could be an issue if the cell you expect to trigger the event has a formula that only refers to cells on other sheets (changes to the cell values the formula refers to would trigger the `Calculate` event but not the `Change` event on the worksheet where the trigger cell is). This isn't the most likely scenario so please explain exactly how you call your function

Comment: @CoachNono: you'll need to show some code: a good place to start would be the UDF which isn't updating.

Comment: I use a button to generate the report. Now, the function that I need to be updated depending on the report is my own vba function named number_of_appearances() so in the cell, I use it as : =number_of_appearances(argument1,argument2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like your UDF might not depend on any cells that change value when your DB is processed.
See [This MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687891.aspx)

Post your UDF (or just its header if you prefer) and an example of its use...

EDIT:
Yes, none of the parameters to the UDF are cell references, therefore the UDF is not triggered to recalculate when data on the shet changes.

You have two choices:
1. rewrite your UDF to include parameter(s) that reference cells that change value when the DB is processed
2. make your UDF volitile (include `Application.Volatile` in the UDF code) **WARNING:** this can be very inefficient, depending on how many time the UDF is used and how intensive its calculation is

EDIT 2:
Heres a refactor of your udf using the first option mentioned:

```
Public Function number_of_appearances(term As String, rng As Range) As Integer
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim appearances As Long

    v = Intersect(rng, rng.Worksheet.UsedRange)
    For j = LBound(v, 2) To UBound(v, 2)
    For i = LBound(v, 1) To UBound(v, 1)
        If v(i, j) = term Then
            appearances = appearances + 1
        End If
    Next i, j
    number_of_appearances = appearances

End Function
```

use like 
    `=number_of_appearances("test";Sheet1!C:C)`

EDIT 3:
If all you are doing is counting number of occurances of a string in a range, consider using
    `=COUNTIF(Sheet1!C:C;"test")`

Comment: Public Function number_of_appearances(term As String, sheet As String, column As Integer) As Integer         =number_of_appearances('test', 'Sheet1', 2)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, the application.volatile does not change the value inside the cells. Strange isn't ? do you have a clue ?

Comment: will need more info...  can you post your UDF code and a snippet of a sheet that uses it?

Comment: Thank you very much ! That is great. I also found that pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+F9 does reactualize the dependencies. For info..

Comment: You're welcome.  CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+F9 forces a recalc of all cells

Comment: Strangely, when I put Application.CalculateFullRebuild at the end of my command_click sub, my cells all have #value. I tried to make the program wait but that doesn't solve anything. But, when I press CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+F9 it works. Do you have a clue ?

Comment: I can get the #Value error if `Application.CalculateFullRebuild` is in both a click event sub and the udf.  Seems `.CalculateFullRebuild` returns an error if called while another call to it is still executing.